# Unable to apply stylesheet as per the screen resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to develope reponsive web site in html for that I've wrote two css files **"large.css"*** for desktop and **"small.css"*** hand held devices. Now I am linking them in head tag of my page as:

```
<link href="Styles/large.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:980px)" />
<link href="Styles/small.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:480px)" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;maximum-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

**HTML code in body tag as:**

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

**large.css :**

```
.content
{
    width: 950px; 
    height: 750px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 461px; 
    left: 0px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**small.css**

```
.content
{
    width: 356px; 
    height: 750px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 461px; 
    left: 0px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

But when I run site in browser, page always reffer to the ***small.css*** style. Which screw up all my design in desktop.

What I want is that when screen width is greater than 980px I want page to reffer ***large.css*** and when it is between 980px to 480px I want the page to reffer ***small.css***.

What is wrong in my above code.
Please give me any solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-width`:

```
<link href="Styles/lasrge.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:980px)" />
<link href="Styles/small.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:979px)" />
```

Comment: Glad I could help. For clarification, using `min-width` means that both conditions are met, so the browser uses both stylesheets. `max-width` is exclusive and creates a distinction between the two. My preference is for keeping media queries in a single css file, and building them progressively, so that the larger screen sizes use the small screen styles and modify or add to them. Using separate files, as in this case, keeps the file size down, which is an advantage. The disadvantage is that you have to maintain two distinct sets of rules, as nothing is inherited.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, probably there is a misspelling on the first stylesheet link **href="Styles/lasrge.css**. Make sure it is not that misspelling the origin of the problem, correcting to **href="Styles/large.css**.

Comment: no the misspelling only in the question. In actual code it is right.

Comment: than, try to replace the link element (of the small.css) media attribute by **screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 979px)**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add two css files

you can do it with using only one single file. Also you just need to write that css which you want to over right.

```
@media (max-width: 980px){ 
    .content{
        width: 950px; 
        height: 750px; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
        position: relative; 
        top: 461px; 
        left: 0px;
        z-index:-1;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 979px){ 
    .content{
        width: 356px; 
        height: 750px; 
    }
}
```